# How to output the line of the function call that created logic error

Tags: c++, matrix, error-handling, macros, line-numbers

I'm creating a Matrix math library with CUDA to improve my CNNs performance (and to understand C++ better).

I would like to be able to add error handling and tell the user (me) what has gone wrong when using the matrix class.

This can be seen in my main file as, in this case, I'm trying to add a 10 * 10 matrix to a 15 * 15 matrix. This is an impossible action and would like some output to tell the user. for example

```
Error in file "Main.cu" on line: 9 (Dimensions inconsistent)
```

If you check inside the function the line number is line number of the check and I've looked at using macros to check but I'm wondering if there is another way without having to call the macro every time I add two matrices together.

**Main.cu**

```
#include "Matrix.cuh"


int main() {
    double* init;
    cudaMallocManaged(&init, sizeof(double));

    Matrix A(10, 10, 2);
    Matrix B(15, 15, 3);
    Matrix C = A + B;

    A.printM("A");
    B.printM("B");
    C.printM("C");

    //cudaFree(init);
    return 0;
}
```

**Matrix.cu**

```
#include "Matrix.cuh"

__global__
void sumMatrix(Matrix* A, Matrix* B, Matrix* C)
{
    int x = blockIdx.x * BLOCK_SIZE + threadIdx.x;
    int y = blockIdx.y * BLOCK_SIZE + threadIdx.y;
    if (x < A->ColumnCount && y < A->RowCount)
    {
        C->VALUES[y * A->ColumnCount + x] = A->VALUES[y * A->ColumnCount + x] + B->VALUES[y * A->ColumnCount + x];
    }
}

__global__
void matrixInit(Row* rows, int R, int C, double* VALUES, double val) {
    int x = blockIdx.x * BLOCK_SIZE + threadIdx.x;
    int y = blockIdx.y * BLOCK_SIZE + threadIdx.y;
    if (x < C && y < R)
    {
        if (x == 0)
        {
            rows[y].Count = C;
            rows[y].values = VALUES + C * y;
        }
        VALUES[y * C + x] = val;
    }
}

Matrix::Matrix(int R, int C, double val)
{
    cudaMallocManaged(&VALUES, R * C * sizeof(double));
    cudaMallocManaged(&rows, R * sizeof(Row));
    RowCount = R;
    ColumnCount = C;

    dim3 gridDim(ceil(C / (double)BLOCK_SIZE), ceil(R / (double)BLOCK_SIZE), 1);
    dim3 blockDim(BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE, 1);
    matrixInit << <gridDim, blockDim >> > (rows, R, C, VALUES, val);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaCheckErrors("MATRIX INIT VAL");
}

Matrix::Matrix(int R, int C)
{
    cudaMallocManaged(&VALUES, R * C * sizeof(double));
    cudaMallocManaged(&rows, R * sizeof(Row));
    RowCount = R;
    ColumnCount = C;

    dim3 gridDim(ceil(C / (double)BLOCK_SIZE), ceil(R / (double)BLOCK_SIZE), 1);
    dim3 blockDim(BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE, 1);
    matrixInit << <gridDim, blockDim >> > (rows, R, C, VALUES, 0);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaCheckErrors("MATRIX INIT VAL");
}

void Matrix::updatePointers()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < RowCount; i++)
    {
        rows[i].values = VALUES + (i * ColumnCount);
    }
}

void Matrix::removePointers()
{
    VALUES = nullptr;
    rows = nullptr;
}

void Matrix::printM(const char* msg)
{
    std::cout << "Matrix " << msg << ": " << RowCount << "*" << ColumnCount << std::endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < RowCount; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < ColumnCount; j++)
        {
            std::cout << rows[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

Matrix Matrix::sum(Matrix B)
{
    Matrix* A_p, * B_p, * C_p;
    Matrix C(RowCount, ColumnCount);

    cudaMallocManaged(&A_p, sizeof(Matrix));
    cudaMallocManaged(&B_p, sizeof(Matrix));
    cudaMallocManaged(&C_p, sizeof(Matrix));

    memcpy(A_p, this, sizeof(Matrix));
    memcpy(B_p, &B, sizeof(Matrix));
    memcpy(C_p, &C, sizeof(Matrix));

    dim3 gridDim(ceil(ColumnCount / (double)BLOCK_SIZE), ceil(RowCount / (double)BLOCK_SIZE), 1);
    dim3 blockDim(BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE, 1);

    sumMatrix << < gridDim, blockDim >> > (A_p, B_p, C_p);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaCheckErrors("SUM");

    B.removePointers();
    C.removePointers();

    return *C_p;
}

Row& Matrix::operator[](size_t i)
{
    if (i >= RowCount)
    {
        std::cout << "OUT OF BOUNDS";
        std::exit(1);
    }
    return rows[i];
}


Matrix& Matrix::operator+(Matrix B)
{
    Matrix C = sum(B);
    Matrix* C_p;
    cudaMallocManaged(&C_p, sizeof(Matrix));
    memcpy(C_p, &C, sizeof(Matrix));
    B.removePointers();
    C.removePointers();
    return *C_p;
}

Matrix::~Matrix()
{
    if (VALUES != nullptr && rows != nullptr)
    {
        cudaFree(VALUES);
        cudaFree(rows);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you use template? so compiler would pinpoint the issue compile time, instead of runtime.

Comment: Unfortunately, operator cannot take extra default parameters (as [`std::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location)), so you cannot do that for `+`, but you could have it for function/method `sum`.

Comment: @Jarod42 I'm not sure how that would help as it would still compile but as soon as it comes to add the matrices it would give me a runtime error in the CUDA kernel "sumMatrix"

Comment: With template, `Matrix<15, 15>(3.) + Matrix<10, 10>(2.)` won't compile as types mismatch.

Comment: @Jarod42, it would also be quite annoying having to mention the line number using "__LINE_"_ every time I sum a matrix. Do you know of any other way

Comment: `std::source_location` does it for you (before there are MACRO such as `__FILE__`, `__LINE__ ` and `__FUNCTION__` which mostly also require user MACRO.

Comment: @Jarod42 thank you I shall try with ```std::source_location```

Comment: @Jarod42 how do I use source location. I'm currently using the latest version of visual studio 2019 and when I include the header file there is no std::source_location class to be found.

Comment: From [compiler_support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support), msvc supports it since `19.29 (16.10)*`, and minimal test in goldbolt compile [here](https://godbolt.org/z/fM96aqhjo)

Comment: @Jarod42 Im using 16.10.3. are there any extra libraries I have to include because I keep getting a ```source_location is not a member of std``` whenever I try and use it. Here is my code                                                                                                  ```#include <source_location>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
 std::source_location test;
}``` sorry im not sure how to format code in comments

Comment: Do you have `/std:c++latest`?